# Подход к написанию SQL базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Подскажите в общих чертах современные подходы к написанию sql бд (неважно какая, mysql, sqlite...).

Необходимо создать простую бд в малой организации учета товаров и расходов.

Из коробки все бд (sqlite, mysql и тд) позволяют работать в консоли (создавать таблицы и запросы) - тут все понятно. Но в консоли же не будут работать сотрудники, например, склада ;). Также есть графические интерфейсы разработчика.

А как происходит интеграция бд с работой конечных пользователей (офисные работники)? Необходимо использовать любой язык (Java, C# и тд) для написания ПО для каждого типа клиента в каждом конкретном случае? Или есть готовые решения  по типу ms access? Как правильно организовать такую систему?

Comment: Всё зависит от того, в каком виде необходимо сделать. Большинство БД поддерживают уровни доступов на просмотри, изменение и удаления. Скажет так по ролям. Через тот же phpmyadmin или datagrip. Если же это сложно для пользователей, то можно написать и свой фрейм для СУБД. Практически на любом языке программирования.

Comment: *Подскажите в общих чертах современные подходы к написанию sql бд* Полный анализ предметной области. Выделение сущностей и атрибутов, связей, процессов. Нормализация. Построение ER-диаграммы. Формирование таблиц БД. Создание клиентского интерфейса.

Comment: Если предполагается несколько видов клиентов, то обычно делают веб интерфейс и сотрудники ходят через браузер. Если со всем по правильному то делается web-api а им потом пользуется и web-фронтэнд и например приложения для мобильных устройств. Ну либо, с учетом что это все для офиса, выбирается язык/платформа разработки под windows

Comment: Приведите примеры языков/платформ. Ведь, в большинстве случае, задачи, как мне кажется, типовые. Зачем в этом случае всегда с нуля писать некий программный код? Например, если бы вам сказали написать бд склада на 1000 сотрудников. Каков бы был алгоритм действий?

Comment: Почему бы не посмотреть готовые решения? Создание и поддержка своего велосипеда в итоге может обойтись куда дороже.

Comment: Так вот, и просветите новичка,  о каких готовых решениях идет речь, если делать, например на основе mysql? ) Много искал, либо плохо, либо каждый изобретает свой.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону фреймворков django, flask, webblocks. Если на "складе" есть сеть и центральный сервер поднять все необходимое не сложно. На стороне конечного пользователя нужен только браузер. Работу с БД обеспечит фреймворк.

Comment: А готовые реализации mysql интерфейсов без использования веб-фреймворков существуют? В сторону каких можно смотреть? Или лучше разрабатывать под конкретную задачу на любом языке программирования?